# Using narrow (25mm-27mm) steel studs for walls

Tags: drywall, walls, studs, sound-proofing, steel

I did some research, watched some videos. All of those shows how to install standard steel studs for walls (50mm-100mm x 50 mm). For ceiling there are more narrow studs, like 60mm x 27mm or 60mm x 25mm.

The problem is that I have only around 40 mm of space for the wall. I want to build an extra wall next to existing brick one. No plumbing or cabling is required, so I don't need any holes.

So I was wondering if it is ok to use 60mm x 25mm (or 27 mm) studs that are usually used for ceiling.

Why I want to build the extra wall? Sound insulation. Already attached expanded cork layer and mass loaded vinyl layer to the brick wall and it works but the effect so far is not as good. I read that in this case it is best to build a second wall that does not have a direct contact with the brick wall. Of course use vibration dampening tapes on stud framing and acoustic sealant around the acoustic plasterboard.

Also saw people attaching acoustic plasterboard directly to brick walls (or use mass loaded vinyl in between) but since the wall gets most of the sound from direct contact to it (e.g. hitting things attached to other side of the wall) I doubt it would be as effective as building extra no-contact wall.

So my question is can you use 25mm or 27mm studs on walls? Also, how large should be the gaps between them? I plan to use acoustic plasterboard (12.5mm width) with the weight of 17kg/m2.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, dividing, non-load bearing walls can be constructed from 2x3" lumber (1.5"x2.5" actual, ~38x64mm). These dimensions seem pretty close to your steel stud dimensions, so I see no reason why not. However, check your local rules & regulations to ensure you're not violating local code.

**Something to consider**:

Everything I've read about sound proofing involves installing *mass*. Steel studs will have less mass than wood studs and smaller studs will have less mass than larger studs. Therefore, while I understand the desire to not loose any more floor space than necessary, you're going to be trading a smidge more floor space for less efficient sound damping.

Comment: Yes, it is about the mass. However, only the mass itself is not enough. It does damper airborne sound very well but vibration sound not so well. The key is having a space between two masses. In my case the second mass would be from acoustic plasterboard as it is much more heavy than studs. Also, my ceiling is 4 meters high and most of the wood studs are up to 3 meters long so would need cutting and joining.

Answer (score 0):

The thin steel stud you're talking about is often used for walls. However it is quite thin, so without being supported by the wall, it will bow. For 2.50m ceiling height, you would put one support at mid-height, for your 4m ceiling height you would need two supports. Without the supports, don't even try.

These supports are a problem in your case because they link the stud to the wall, which creates an acoustic link. This will defeat your soundproofing efforts. This type of construction is usually meant for thermal insulation, where you want thin studs to use thicker insulation, but it isn't effective for soundproofing.

You should read the technical docs from the local drywall/stud manufacturer, you will find details about how to build it so it doesn't fall apart. Without support, I think you'll need at least 70mm thick steel studs, which would exceed your 40mm thickness target.

You may be able to find acoustic supports, which are built with a rubber element to dampen vibration and prevent transmission of noise from the wall to the drywall. That would allow using thin studs, but these acoustic supports may not be thin enough for your case.

Another option for soundproofing is to cover the wall with semi-rigid rockwool, fiberglass or wood fiber panels that are normally meant for underfloor insulation and soundproofing. Unlike the soft ones, these panels are tough enough that you can glue them to the brick, then glue drywall to them. If you can find readymade drywall panels with a fiberglass insulation backing, this will also work. If you want soundproofing, don't use styrofoam backed panels, these do nothing for insulation.

The idea is that fiberglass, even the semi-rigid ones, is still quite soft, so it will be strong enough to hold the drywall to your bricks, but it will not allow vibrations to couple straight into it.

The "glue" to use is the same cheap plaster-based powder adhesive mortar that you'd use to hang drywall on a cement wall.

Note mass loaded vinyl and cork are quite useless for soundproofing as they are laid directly on the brick wall, so if that vibrates, they vibrate too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added the cork layer before doing the research.. The mass loaded vinyl works for airborne sounds. Yes, I read the "manual"/rules of maker of studs/drywall (Knauf), which is approved by local authorities and it uses supports which are screwed to the wall. I was thinking about using glue, but I wonder if it is strong enough to hold the heavy 17kg/sqm weight of the plasterboard?

Comment: Styrofoam-backed drywall is usually slapped on the wall with glue. Well it's not really glue, it's an adhesive plaster-based mortar with additives that make it really sticky and not runny, so it stays where it should instead of dripping on the floor. I have no idea what the English name is for this stuff, but it's about 8€ for a bag of 25kg, so it's really cheap. It will not stick to paint, so the wall has to be prepared first.

Comment: There used to be rockwool-backed drywall (one 10mm sheet of drywall and 40mm semi-rigid rockwool) that was very good for soundproofing, but offered lower insulation than styrofoam. So I'm not sure you can still buy it, because most people focus on insulation. It was installed with the same adhesive mortar. Even if the rockwool isn't very "solid", there is a large surface area of adhesive, so it stays stuck pretty well.

Comment: I found a few of "sandwitch" panels for soundproofing, such as https://www.noisestopsystems.co.uk/shop/wall-soundproofing/noisestop-silent-panel/ . Makers say they are really good for sound insulation. But those are specifically in UK. Could not find anything like that neither in my country nor in whole EU (with EU-wide shipping).

Comment: It's always the same type of build, drywall for weight on the outside, and a soft compliant material on the inside, that still has to be strong enough to hang on the wall... My suggestion was to use rockwool/fiberglass, but foam would probably work too.